# Generate colors between #CCCCCC and #3B5998 for a color meter?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a Javascript code and I want to implement a color meter.

I need to write a function that takes a int between i - j, and based on how high that number is, it will return a color between #CCCCCC (i on the scale) and #3B5998 (j on the scale).

Similar to how this work:

[image]

Comment: You should start by defining a function that goes from one color to the next, then it's reasonably easy figuring out a way to map the distinct colors to integers.

Comment: Do you need these colors in RGB (HEX)? Because it would be much nicer to implement using HSL colors, where the hue is fixed and only saturation and lighntess need to be calculated  - which is not that hard:  https://jsfiddle.net/m3qgowx4/ (code in ES6).

Comment: Another demo: https://jsfiddle.net/baz3v5z5/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the delta of the colors and divide by the wanted range (minus one) and multiply for the given position. Then convert back to a hex value.

```js
function getColor(i, left, right) {
    function c(c0, c1) {
        return ('00' + Math.floor(
            parseInt(c0, 16) * (right - i) / (right - left) +
            parseInt(c1, 16) * (i - left) / (right - left)
        ).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return c(color[0].slice(0, 2), color[1].slice(0, 2)) + c(color[0].slice(2, 4), color[1].slice(2, 4)) + c(color[0].slice(4, 6), color[1].slice(4, 6));
}

var color = ['CCCCCC', '3B5998'],
    min = 4000,
    max = 40902,
    span, i, v;

span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = min + '&nbsp;'
document.body.appendChild(span);
for (i = min; i <= max; i += (max - min) / 68) {
    v = getColor(i, min, max);
    span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    span.style.backgroundColor = '#' + v;
    span.title = 'i: ' + Math.floor(i) + '\n#' + v;
    document.body.appendChild(span);
}
span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = '&nbsp;' + max;
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: @AngelosChalaris, it was just a bit more compley, because all three colors have to be independent calculated.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution using HSL color model, which is better suited for this sort of things. The ingredients of a HSL are: Hue, Saturation and Lightness.

You have two colors: `#3B5998` == `hsl(221, 40%, 41%)`, and
`#cccccc` == `hsl(221, 0%, 80%)` (since it's 0% saturation the hue doesn't matter here).

Now you only need a way to convert the integer value in the range between min and max to percentage and apply this percentage to Saturation (0..40) and Lightness (41..80).

```
const scale =  ( min, max, number) => (( number - min ) / ( max - min ));
```

Given minimum, maximum value and a number returns where the number falls on a scale from 0 to 1, e.g. `scale( 0, 100, 50 ) === 0.5`

```
const range = ( min, max, percentage ) => ( min + (max - min) * percentage );
```

Given minimum, maximum value and percentage return the number on the percentage point between min and max, e.g. `range( 0, 100, 0.5 ) === 50`.

To saturate and lighten the color you need to calculate the S and L values given the point on scale and min/max values. The color object used in examples is in the format `{ h:221, s :0, l:0 }`

```
const colorTween = ( colorA, colorB, percentage ) => ({
    h : range( colorA.h, colorB.h, percentage ) | 0,
    s : range( colorA.s, colorB.s, percentage ) | 0,
    l : range( colorA.l, colorB.l, percentage ) | 0
});
```

The `colorTween` function takes two colors and applies the percentage of difference between min and max to the difference between h, s, and l of these two colors.

```
const getColor = ( number, min, max ) => {
    const percentage = scale( min, max, number );
    return colorTween({ h: 221, s:0, l:80}, { h: 221, s:40, l:41 }, percentage)
}
```

In action: https://jsfiddle.net/tbcwwrgr/

In your case hue is constant, but you could also make a "rainbow" scale using `colorTween({ h: 0, s:100, l:50}, { h: 255, s:100, l:50 }, percentage)`

Answer (score 1):

A *naive* method would be to take start and end values for both colors, calculate a percentage from the startpoint and get the difference, then convert back to hex. I converted your colors `#CCCCCC` and `#3B5998` to their RGB values, passed them to a function which does this and, using code from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/xcqpF/1/light/), I converted them to hex values. You can see the results below:

```js
//Function to convert hex format to a rgb color
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
  rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?[\s+]?\([\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?/i);
  return (rgb && rgb.length === 4) ? "#" +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) : '';
}

function getGradientColor(startColorRed, startColorGreen, startColorBlue, endColorRed, endColorGreen, endColorBlue, gradientSize, gradientPoint) {
  var diffRed = endColorRed - startColorRed;
  var diffGreen = endColorGreen - startColorGreen;
  var diffBlue = endColorBlue - startColorBlue;

  diffRed = (diffRed * gradientPoint / gradientSize) + startColorRed;
  diffGreen = (diffGreen * gradientPoint / gradientSize) + startColorGreen;
  diffBlue = (diffBlue * gradientPoint / gradientSize) + startColorBlue;
  return rgb2hex('rgba(' + parseInt(diffRed) + ',' + parseInt(diffGreen) + ',' + parseInt(diffBlue) + ')');
}

var startColorRed = 204;
var startColorGreen = 204;
var startColorBlue = 204;

var endColorRed = 59;
var endColorGreen = 89;
var endColorBlue = 152;


console.log(getGradientColor(startColorRed, startColorGreen, startColorBlue, endColorRed, endColorGreen, endColorBlue, 1000, 0));

console.log(getGradientColor(startColorRed, startColorGreen, startColorBlue, endColorRed, endColorGreen, endColorBlue, 1000, 510));

console.log(getGradientColor(startColorRed, startColorGreen, startColorBlue, endColorRed, endColorGreen, endColorBlue, 1000, 1000));
```

Comment: @KasimJasarevic, then mark one of the answers as accepted, it is considered quite rude just to take an answer and leave ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
function getColor(i, j, n) {
   var r = 0xCC-Math.round((0xCC-0x3b)*(j-n)/(j-i));
   var g = 0xCC-Math.round((0xCC-0x59)*(j-n)/(j-i));
   var b = 0xCC-Math.round((0xCC-0x98)*(j-n)/(j-i));

   // not really necessary for your color selection, included for completeness
   var twoDigits=function(s) {
     if (s.length==1) return "0"+s;
     return s;
   }

   return "#"+
          twoDigits(r.toString(16))+
          twoDigits(g.toString(16))+
          twoDigits(b.toString(16));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a code where you input a number and according to value the output box shows the hex color value between the two given range.[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjgp9fqg/)

Here is the code

```js
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function() {
  var inp = document.getElementById("myInput").value;


  var start = 0x3B5998,
    end = 0xcccccc,
    myResult;
  var cnt = 0;

  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (start == end) {
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    };
    myResult = (start).toString(16);
    if (myResult.length < 8) {

      myResult = "0000000".substring(0, 8 - myResult.length) + myResult;
    }
    cnt++;
    start++;
    if (inp == cnt) {
      document.getElementById("result").value = myResult;
      console.log(myResult);
      clearInterval(intervalId);

    }

  }, 1);

}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myInput" placeholder="enter a number" />
<button id="clickMe" onclick="myFunction()">
CLICK TO FIND HEX VALUE
</button>
<input type="text" id="result" />
```